# After Converting VB To C# FileSystem.Dir

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have converted from VB to C# and unable to fix `FileSystem.Dir`.

```
tFile = FileSystem.Dir(Path.Combine(path, file));
```

Comment: `System.IO.Directory` is probably what you want

Answer (score 2):

While one usually doesn't use the assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in C# code, there's nothing stopping you from doing so.  Just add a reference and find it in the list of standard assemblies then make sure you have:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

While there might be more idiomatic C# solutions, using the original method is less likely to introduce a breaking change in porting the code.

Comment: Without using the assembly. How can we write it

Comment: @WiSeeker: Goodacre just threw out a type name - I don't see a fully-formed suggestion - just an obscure hint.

Comment: This is a good answer - VB's FileSystem.Dir is a quirky function (like many VB functions) with no direct equivalent in the rest of the .NET Framework, so why try to simulate it's behavior?  Just use it directly.

Comment: @Nagaraj: Why not use the assembly directly?  It's part of every version of the .NET Framework.  It'll be difficult to simulate every little nuance of this function using just the System.IO types.